# ArrowKT - Lens invoke giving compilation error

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I'm trying to follow [this documentation](https://arrow-kt.io/docs/optics/lens/) about `Lens` in Arrow. However when I try to write a Lens

```
data class Player(val health: Int)

val playerLens: Lens<Player, Int> = Lens(
    get = { player -> player.health },
    set = { player, value -> player.copy(health = value) }
)
```

I get the following error:

```
4 type arguments expected for operator fun <S, T, A, B> invoke(): PLens<S, T, A, B>
```

I see that `Lens<S, T>` is a typealias for `PLens<S, S, T, T>`, so why this compilation error?

Kotlin version 1.3.50

Arrow Optics version 0.10.0

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your error, it works for me. Could you please provide kotlin and arrow version you are using? Or a full sample project

Comment: @EvgenyBovykin Edited with the versions

Comment: I've copy-pasted your code and it works fine for me: https://github.com/missingdays/ultimate-test/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main.kt
Here you can see that I'm using the same versions as you provided: https://github.com/missingdays/ultimate-test/blob/master/build.gradle#L20

Comment: @EvgenyBovykin I cloned your repo and it is working fine. Is arrow-syntax needed as well? I don't have that dependency.

Comment: Using arrow-syntax doesn't change anything, still the same error. Weird.

Comment: Here's a sample project with the problem: https://github.com/m0skit0/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin typealias doesn't work here as expected. When calling constructor, you need to specify 4 params here:

```
Lens<Player, Player, String, String>(
        get = { v -> v.health },
        set = { v, value -> player.copy(health = value)  }
    )
```

Our don't specify them at all, compiler could infer them for you from lambda parameters types

```
Lens(
        get = { player: Player -> player.health },
        set = { player: Player, value: Int -> player.copy(health = value) }
    )
```